# Masking Card Data Using log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, pci-compliance

I want to mask track data , card data and etc , my pattern of logging is as follows
plain text  : userID=1234|trackData=789654asdas|pin=897|userName=445566
Masked text : userID=1234|trackData=|pin=|userName=445566

i don't want to print this data which is sensitive ,
is there any way to do so ,
also i am not using spring boot or spring mvc architecture , this is normal rest api's.

Comment: The best plan is to mask the data *before* you create the log entry.  For example, if the above is the result of calling `toString()` on an object, change the `toString()` method, or create the log message in a way that doesn't call `toString()`.